# DetailDisclosureButton on Android?

Tags: android

is there something like a DetailDisclosureButton on Android's ListView?

On iPhone you can configure the cells AccessoryType.

Is there an equivalent to the DetailDisclosureButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there's anything baked into the SDK, but it would be relatively easy to create one using a custom ListView adapter.