# What's the name of this Button?

Tags: android, button, checkbox

Which is the name of the method/library which collapses/extends a list triggered by the user action?
Please see the image below to understand my use case.
[image: This is what I am looking for]

Comment: Yes, thanks!..Such basic questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6832164/1531971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I can see you have a List View with one Item, and on press you want to show a sublist. I guess you do not know Android terms and you are thinking from an abstract design point of view.

In more technical terms you need to expand a ListView when the user touches the item.

Here you can find a tutorial to use [ExpandibleListVIew](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Please consider that **nowdays is really used in place of ListView a library called [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)**, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419161/expandable-list-with-recyclerview) and maybe even better this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items?noredirect=1&lq=1) where you can find a valid method that explain your UX use case, without recurring to external libraries but capitalizing the method `onBindViewHolder`, as allegedly recommended at a Google I/O official conference.

RecyclerView offers much more functionalities, animations and should be the best option to go if the app increases in complexity, namely a real life scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can use expandable recyclerview

eg
[Expandable recycler view](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9qScBaKfnM)